# Configuring an Eclipse environment

Tags: windows, eclipse, configuration

I have been configuring an eclipse environment on my laptop. It takes an annoying number of steps, since I am trying to add in disparate features, such as support for mercurial, subversion, C++, arduino, and Android.

Once it's done, however, is all the state located in my eclipse directory?  Can I just save that directory and install it on multiple computers?

I am on Windows, so this question is complicated by whatever nonsense is in the registry.  I wish I could be on Linux, so I could just be asking what environment variables to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy and paste your Windows Eclipse install dir anywhere and eclipse should work just fine. I've done this a number of times. However I do not think it'll port across OS's since eclipse download contains platform specific files. In theory, the eclipse project and classpath file (these contain most of the config) should be portable across platforms and I've used the same ones on Windows and Linux. Just open them in a file editor to make sure they contain relative paths only.

Comment: Thanks!  That's really great that I can just copy around the directory, and slightly annoying that I can't port it to all OSs.  I will just wait a couple of days to check yours as the answer in case anyone else has something terrific to say.

Comment: In theory it would work across multiple platforms as well, however the eclipse download contains OS specific binaries. Everything else that Eclipse itself depends on, i.e. the plugin, add-on's etc are platform independent.